# AngularJS fake $httpBackend.whenPOST() Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

Pretty new to AngularJS and got a mock $httpBackend working as described in the docs (see here:http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend). I can reproduce the GET code e.g.:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(phones);
```

The POST, method, however, fails with an angular-mocks.js error. This is what I specify to happen on POST:

```
      $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method,url,data){
        console.log(data);
        phones.push(angular.fromJson(data));
  });
```

This is how I call the POST from the controller:

```
  var newPhone = {name:'New Phone'};
  $http.post('/forecasts/types.json', newPhone);
```

And this is what I see in the console in response:

```
{"name":"New Phone"}  app.js:167

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined angular-mocks.js:876
(anonymous function) angular-mocks.js:876
completeOutstandingRequest angular.js:2930
(anonymous function) angular.js:3209
```

My code looks pretty much the same as the docs. The function is called when POSTed to but I can't figure out why it won't run.

**Edit (thanks to Josh David Miller for his comment re a fiddle)** Here is a fiddle that reproduces the error: http://jsfiddle.net/elcabo/btbds/3/
The fiddle is based on the example in the Angular docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend) and the angular fiddle for mockE2E $httpBackend (http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/DQHdk/)

Has anyone encountered this before or have any ideas on how to attack this?

I've searched pretty wide for a solution/relevant posts but can't find any, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that errors out on Plunker or jsFiddle so we can tinker?

Comment: Thanks Josh. I should have posted a fiddle when I posted the question. My bad. Working off too little sleep. I've reproduced the error in a fiddle and edited my question to include it.

Comment: I'll take a look at the fiddle, but the first thing I noticed is that you're using a version of Angular that is *really* outdated (0.10.6 vs 1.0.x). Is this intentional or can I update it to the latest version?

Comment: Gold! Thanks Josh. The version of angular in the fiddle was carried over from the docs' fiddle, which I forked. My project uses v1.0.3 which I installed using yeoman. It now works with your edits. So simple. Gah. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I updated your jsFiddle, which now works: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/EgMpe/.

First, the version of AngularJS was extraordinarily old. I updated it from 0.10.6 to 1.0.3. With that change came many syntactic changes, which you can find in the fiddle.

But the issue you were having was from not returning a value in your `$httpBackend.whenPOST` method. The `respond` method is expected to return a value indicating the status, response body, and headers. The verbose example I included in the working fiddle is:

```js
$httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
  console.log('Received these data:', method, url, data, headers);
  phones.push(angular.fromJson(data));
  return [200, {}, {}];
});
```

The array returned is a response status of `200`, an empty response body, and an empty set of headers (i.e. use the defaults).

I also added a `whenGET` so you can see them working together:

```js
$httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(function(method,url,data) {
  console.log("Getting phones");
  return [200, phones, {}];
});
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but I'm curious how the `Main` controller is being applied in your fiddle? I don't see `ng-controller` or `.controller()` anywhere -- is it a special case that a top-level function named `Main` will automatically be injected and used?

Comment: @ken This is one of the reasons I like Plunker better; click "Fiddle Options" at left and you will see the body tag definition, in which the `ngController` directive sits.